# Creating File in arduino's Memory while arduino is operating

Tags: file, arduino, arduino-uno

In my arduino project i have to store some integers(25 to be specific) in a file in arduino's memory (as i have arduino UNO and it doesn't have built-in port for SD Card) and read that file next-time i start the arduino .

Also my arduino is not connected to PC or laptop so i can't use file system of PC or laptop

so is there any way possible doing it ?

Comment: Seems a hard task, as no SD card is present to persist to and also there is no connection to "outer world" of other storage devices. How should that possible work, assuming you want to retrieve that data ever again in the future.

Comment: Note, for more Arduino-related questions, you can also check out [arduino.stackexchange.com](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Arduino Uno has 1KB of non-volatile EEPROM memory, which you can use for this purpose. An integer is 2 bytes, so you should be able to store over 500 ints this way.

This example sketch should write a couple of integers from 10 to 5 into EEPROM memory:

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

void setup() {
  int address = 0;   //Location we want the data to be put.

  for (int value = 10; value >= 5; --value) 
  {
    // Write the int at address
    EEPROM.put(eeAddress, value)
    // Move the address, so the next value will be written after the first.
    address += sizeof(int);
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

This example is a stripped down version of the one in the [EEPROM.put documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/EEPROMPut). Other examples can be found in the [documentation of the various EEPROM functions](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM).
Another nice tutorial on the subject can be found on [tronixstuff](http://tronixstuff.com/2011/03/16/tutorial-your-arduinos-inbuilt-eeprom/).

By the way, if you need more memory, you could also use EEPROM memory banks. These are small ICs. They are available for very low prices in low amounts of memory, typically from 1KB to 256KB. Not much in terms of modern computing, but a huge expansion compared to the 1KB you have by default.